# Navigate to specific screen on opening notification with Firebase Messaging & React Navigation (React Native, Android)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got a react native app using remote notifications with firebase messaging and react navigation. Everything is working great, except after a while (or occasionally) the notification listeners don't work. It could take up to 2 weeks until I get any issues whatsoever. It usually happens when the app has been started for a long time but not used, then when opening a notification, the `onNotificationOpenedApp` doesn't run, i.e I just see the index screen. I am using "react-native-bootsplash" if that could have anything to do with it?

Also, sometimes an old notification triggers a listener, and I assume that is `getInitialNotification` that is being invoked twice (or multiple times). Does android semi-close apps that hasn't been used for a while, and then corrupt the listeners when the app opens again? It seems like the app unmounts partially, and then mounts with issues. As soon as the issue occurs, it is way more likely it will continue happening until I restart the app.

Here's the code for registering the listeners:

`getInitialNotification`
When the user opens the app via a notification, this will be run and return the notification. This is done inside the `getInitialUrl` prop passed to `NavigationContainer` (react-navigation component) This is recommended in their docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#linkinggetinitialurl)

```js
<NavigationContainer
  ref={setNavigationRef}
  linking={{
    config: {
      initialRouteName: 'SignedIn',
    },
    getInitialURL: async () => {
      try {
        // If app was opened with deeplink
        const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
        if (url !== null) return url;

        const notification = await messaging().getInitialNotification();

        if (notification !== null) {
          const {data} = notification;
          if (data!.type === 'ARTICLE') {
            return `${rootUrl}/site/news/${data!.id}`;
          }
          if (data!.type === 'TRANSFER') {
            return `${rootUrl}/site/player/${data!.id}`;
          }
        }

        return null;
      } catch (error) {
        return null;
      }
    },
  }}>
  <App />
</NotificationContainer>
```

Inside the index file (App.tsx) I also register a listener for opening a notification when the app is already started but in the background, using `onNotificationOpenedApp`

`onNotificationOpenedApp`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribeOnNotificationOpenedApp =
      messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
        if (!remoteMessage.data) return;
        const {type, id} = remoteMessage.data;
        if (!id) return;
        if (type === 'TRANSFER') {
          loadPlayer(Number(id));
        } else {
          loadArticle(Number(id));
        }
      });

  return unsubscribeOnNotificationOpenedApp;
}, [])
```